# Does browserify work on Chrome OS?

Tags: browserify, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am making a chrome app that uses a NodeJS library but I'm wondering if I use browserify to convert the Node library (avrgirl-arduino) to JS, will it work on ChromeOS? I don't have a Chrome OS device to test this on, as my school chromebook doesn't allow me to load unpacked extensions.

Comment: I'm not sure with this. But I suggest you to check these links [chrome-os](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-os) and [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) to understand more about these two things. I also suggest you to check this [Atom on chromebook](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-on-chromebook-was-lets-talk-chromeos-resolved/8644), it's discussed here how the browserify work.